# How to add bibliography to the table of contents when using bibitem

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, pdftex, kile, bibitem

In order to write the bibliography, I am using this code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{name} Authors, {\em Name of the article}.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{quotchap} for different chapters titles layout
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tocloft} %to personalize table of contents
\usepackage{hyperref} %hyperlinks
\usepackage{graphicx} %figures
\usepackage{amsmath} %math
\usepackage{amsfonts} %to do the bold W
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{float} %to force position of figures
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage[notindex]{tocbibind} you will no longer need to provide the instruction \addcontentsline{toc}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}%to remove contents from table of contents and to add bibliography to it.




%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} To add sections in the table of contents 


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE{\bf Abstract}}\\
\vspace{9mm}
I hope it will be an important thesis.
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%to reset the page number.

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}\epigraph{``Frase''}{Autore}
Hello
\chapter{Argument 1}
Hello

\chapter{An other argument}
Hello


%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments} 

\begin{thebibliography}{bibliography}
     \bibitem{Article} Authors {\em Paper} .


\end{thebibliography}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}









\end{document}
```

But in this way the bibliography looks like a **chapter** because in
this page there is for example "chapter 4", then the **Bibliography** and in the table of contents it is added with the number of the chapter on the left, like **4 Bibliography....number of its page**. To sum up, the table of contents is this:

[image]

Since the bibliography is in fact in a chapter:

[image]

I tried to use `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}` as suggested in different places but it does not work. I am using Kile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. We need your help in showing us what you have done so that we can try and help you.

Comment: I have done it @PeterWilson.

Comment: Well, what do you *want* it to look like? You're using the `numbib` option which is literally an instruction to number the bibliography. If you want it like an unnumbered chapter like "Acknowledgements", then don't use the `numbib` option. `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Comment: Many thanks @frabjous .